# How can I improve the API of a pure function that returns state in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, state, immutability

I am attempting to write a function which given some function `f` memoizes `f` in such a way that after defining `g = memoize f` followed by `g x` all subsequent invocations of `g` with the argument `x` simply returns the cached result.

However, I am struggling to come up with an implementation that improves upon the explicit state passing that's required with the following:

```
memoize :: Ord t => (t -> a) -> Map t a -> t -> Map t a
memoize f m a = case Map.lookup a m of
    Just _  -> m
    Nothing -> Map.insert a (f a) m
```

with a contrived example to show its usage:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  let memoPlusOne = memoize (+ 1) in
    let m = memoPlusOne Map.empty 1
      in let mm = memoPlusOne m 1
        in print mm
```

I am aware that there are [other, better ways to memoize functions in Haskell](https://wiki.haskell.org/Memoization), but my question is more concerned with improving on the general pattern of passing state to a function to avoid any state mutations that would otherwise be encapsulated as in other languages, e.g. as in this example in Ocaml:

```
let memo_rec f =
  let h = Hashtbl.create 16 in
  let rec g x =
    try Hashtbl.find h x
    with Not_found ->
      let y = f g x in
      (* update h in place *)
      Hashtbl.add h x y;
      y
  in
  g
```

Comment: In OCaml mutable state is not required. You simply need to use `Map.Make` to create a map functor and use that in place of `Hashtbl`.

Comment: In OCaml we can mutate data using side effects everywhere, so it's not an issue. In Haskell side effects are prohibited, so it's more complex. One has to either exploit a lazy data structure (not the strict `Map`) and likely obtain sub-optimal performance, or subvert the system using `unsafe` functions so to perform mutation/side effects anyway. Since the side effect is not observable from outside (the memoized function behaves as a pure one) this does not break referential transparency. You could check Hoogle/Hackage for memoization libraries and study their approach.

Comment: My suggestion is: don't reinvent the wheel and don't toy with `unsafe` stuff in serious code. Rather, take an existing memoization library and use that -- in that way you take no risk to wreak havoc.

Comment: Yeah, I should have perhaps been more explicit, the implementation of the `memoize` function provided was really only for illustrative purposes. I was more concerned with learning about different patterns for state passing/encapsulating mutations in haskell. The question actually came about as I am working through [Category Theory for Programmers](https://bartoszmilewski.com/2014/10/28/category-theory-for-programmers-the-preface/) and defining a `memoize` function is part of one of the exercises in the text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> my question is more concerned with improving on the general pattern of passing state to a function to avoid any state mutations that would otherwise be encapsulated as in other languages

There are lots of ways to do fun things with immutable state in Haskell!  I can give some examples, but I also feel obligated to point out that the most efficient and user-friendly version of `memoize` will likely use `unsafe` under the hood, and if that's what you want, you're probably better off using an existing library than messing with it yourself.  But, if you're experimenting, then have at it!

That said, before we begin with new tricks, let's take a look at what you've created it.  The biggest problem with your current code is that the type is off.  You have `memoize f m :: t -> Map t a`, which doesn't even produce the expected result of `f t` as expected.  After all, the theoretically best type signature for `memoize` is `(t -> a) -> t -> a`.

You can fix this by changing `memoize` to:

```hs
memoize :: Ord t => (t -> a) -> Map t a -> t -> (Map t a, a)
memoize f m t = case Map.lookup t m of
    Just a  -> (m, a)
    Nothing -> let a = f t in (Map.insert t a m, a)
```

With this, you compute the new memoized state but also return the result, which is ultimately what memoizing is for anyway.  This may seem like an irrelevant change (can't you just extract the right `a` from the `Map t a` anyway, you might be asking?) but it's useful to use this type signature when exploring how to handle state.

---

Now, to get back to your question: how can we improve on this general pattern of passing state?  You may notice that your function takes a state and returns a new state, and this is what the `State` monad is all about.  Indeed, `State` is simply defined as:

```hs
newtype State s a = State {runState :: s -> (s, a)}
```

(In the [transformers package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.6.1.0/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-State-Lazy.html#t:State), where you might import it, the type is actually a bit different, but it's isomorphic to this.)  So, you could rewrite `memoize` to be in the `State` monad like so:

```hs
memoize :: Ord t => (t -> a) -> t -> State (Map t a) a
memoize f t = do
    m <- get
    case Map.lookup t m of
        Just a  -> pure a
        Nothing -> do
            let a = f t
            put (Map.insert t a m)
            pure a
```

Annoyingly, you can only use this while you're in the monad.  For instance:

```hs
main :: IO ()
main = do
  let memoPlusOne = memoize (+ 1)
  flip runState Map.empty $ do
    res1 <- memoPlusOne 1
    res2 <- memoPlusOne 3
    print [res1, res2]
```

You can also use `evalState` instead of `runState` if you're interested in the memo-table when you're done.

---

Instead of hiding the state in a monad, we can hide the state directly in the function.  That is, instead of returning a new state, let's return a new function:

```hs
newtype Memoized t a = Memo { runMemo :: t -> (Memoized t a, a) }

memoize :: Ord t => (t -> a) -> Memoized t a
memoize f = Memo $ go Map.empty
  where
    go m t = case Map.lookup t m of
      Just a  -> (Memo $ go m, a)
      Nothing -> let a = f t in (Memo $ go $ Map.insert t a m, a)
```

This trick bundles up the state in a new `Memoized` object every time you call the memoized function.  So, as long as you always use the new `Memoized` object every time you make it, you're sure to always be memoizing.  Consider this version of `main`:

```hs
main :: IO ()
main = do
  let memoPlusOne = memoize (+ 1)
  let (memoPlusOne', res1) = runMemo memoPlusOne 1
  let (memoPlusOne'', res2) = runMemo memoPlusOne' 3
  print [res1, res2]
```

Comment: Wonderful! These types of patterns are exactly what I was looking for. Wondering if you have any sources for learning more about working with immutable state/the general abstractions available in Haskell? Thanks @ddub

Comment: Should have been more clear: the general abstractions available around state "mutations"*

Answer (score 5):

Haskell has exactly one safe, pure API for mutation: in lazy evaluation, thunks are modified in-place the first time they're entered. So! If you want a pure API that does mutation, you have to find a way to use lazy-evaluation mutation to serve the needs of whatever other mutation you wanted to do.

So, the basic idea here is that the thing we want to do is have a `Map` which has *every* input already available as a key, but where the outputs are thunks awaiting evaluation. Ideally, inputs we haven't called the function on are also somewhere in a thunk that's awaiting expansion, too, so that we don't start off with a ridiculously large `Map` in memory.

Unfortunately, `Map` is spine-strict. This means we can't reasonably do the latter bit (of mutably expanding the data structure); and for infinitely-large types, we can't do the former bit (of having every key available). So we'll have to make our own. We'll leave the hard part of figuring out how to lazily enumerate all the keys of our new `Tree`-based `Map`-alike to a type-class.

```
data Tree a = Tree a (Tree a) (Tree a) deriving Functor

class ToBits a where
    allValues :: Tree a
    toBits :: a -> [Bool]
```

We'll need a way to index into these trees.

```
index :: Tree a -> [Bool] -> a
index (Tree a _ _) [] = a
index (Tree _ f _) (False:path) = index f path
index (Tree _ _ t) (True :path) = index t path
```

We'll demand that instances satisfy the law `index allValues (toBits a) == a`. With this class, we can quickly write our memoization function:

```
memo :: ToBits a => (a -> b) -> (a -> b)
memo f = index (f <$> allValues) . toBits
```

For example, for `Integer`, we might write:

```
instance ToBits Integer where
    allValues = Tree 0 (negate <$> go 1 0) (go 1 0) where
        go pow n = Tree (pow + n) (go (2*pow) n) (go (2*pow) (pow+n))
    toBits n = case compare n 0 of
        LT -> False:go (-n)
        EQ -> []
        GT -> True:go n
        where
        go 1 = []
        go n = let (q, r) = n `quotRem` 2 in (r==1) : go q
```

We can try it out. The traditional thing is `fib`:

```
fib :: Integer -> Integer
fib n = if n < 2
    then n
    else fib (n-1) + fib (n-2)

mfib :: Integer -> Integer
mfib = memo fib
```

In ghci:

```
> mfib 30
832040
(1.05 secs, 519,591,368 bytes)
> mfib 30
832040
(0.00 secs, 75,120 bytes)
```

Nice. Except... *traditionally*, the memoized version of `fib` works really fast for really big inputs, and this one... doesn't. What's up?

Well, we've memoized `fib` -- that is, if we call `mfib`, it dispatches to `fib` only if we just passed a new number it never saw before. But the *implementation of `fib` itself* isn't using the memoized version. There's various things we can do about this. The standard trick in the libraries is to expose a `fix`-alike instead of `memo` as shown here. But as long as we're requiring the user to change the definition of the recursive functions they want to memoize, we might as well just do it inline. So another alternative is:

```
mfib' :: Integer -> Integer
mfib' = memo $ \n -> if n < 2
    then n
    else mfib' (n-1) + mfib' (n-2)
```

Now the definition of our memoized `fib` calls the memoized `fib`, as needed. And, as hoped, it's now much faster even on the first call. And it still is doing the memoization thing, we just have to try a bigger input to notice.

```
> mfib' 30
832040
(0.00 secs, 248,096 bytes)
> mfib' 10000
<a truly enormous number>
(0.33 secs, 167,152,008 bytes)
> mfib' 10000
<a truly enormous number>
(0.01 secs, 1,650,816 bytes)
```